# jquery $.ajax() call and IE

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, internet-explorer

I am currently loading an xml file using jquery's ajax function. The content from the file is not being loaded or parsed in IE, currently. I have read several places that I need to specify the correct response header from my xml, but I'm not sure where to do that, since most of the examples I've found pertain to xml generated via php or another language. My 'dataType' in my ajax call is currently 'html'. I'm not sure if this is what I need to change or if I need to change something in my xml file, or if it is something different all together. I appreciate any help given! I don't know that it helps much, but here is the code I am using to retrive the contents of the xml file:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'images/gallery-images/gallery-images.xml',
dataType: "html",
success: function(parseXML){

 $(parseXML).find('section').each(function(){

    var $section = $(this),
        photos = $section.find('photo'),
        videos = $section.find('video'),
        photoContainer = $('<div></div>', { id : $section.attr('id'), 'class' : 'gallery-section' });
    var videoContainer = $('<div></div>', { id : 'video-inner' });

    photos.each(function(){

        var photo = $(this),
        imageurl = photo.attr('imageurl'),
        title = photo.find('title').text(),
        description = photo.find('description').html(),
        kind = photo.find('description').attr('type');
        icon = photo.find('icon').attr('source');
            iconClass = photo.find('icon').attr('class');

        var photoWrapper = $('<div class="photo"></div>'),
            imageElem = $('<img />', { 'src' : imageurl, 'class' : 'gallery-photo' }),
            photoInfo = $('<div></div>', { 'class' : 'photo-info ' + kind }),
            iconInsert = $('<img />', { 'src' : icon, 'class' : iconClass }),
            header = $('<h1></h1>', { text: title }),
            photoDescription = $('<div></div>', { html: description });

        photoInfo.append(iconInsert).append(header).append(photoDescription);    
        photoWrapper.append(imageElem).append(photoInfo);
        photoContainer.append(photoWrapper); 

    });

    videos.each(function(){

        var video = $(this).html();
        photoContainer.append(videoContainer);
        videoContainer.append(video);
    });  
        $('#photo-viewer-inner').append(photoContainer);
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have already mentioned, your `dataType` needs to be `"xml"`. After that, you should be able to traverse your xml in all browsers without issues ***as long as the xml is valid***.

IE chokes on invalid xml much more often than other browsers.

Comment: I am amidst validating my xml. I will check back momentarily.